# jQuery animate / load not working properly first time

Tags: jquery

When a certain link is clicked the following code is executed:

```
div.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, function ()
{
    $(this).load(url, function ()
    {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
    });
});
```

It works perfectly every time, except the first time. The following happens in various browsers:

The div contains the loaded data but remains blank until the link is clicked again. It does not have a style/opacity attribute and setting opacity to 1 in the dev tools doesn't show the div.

I tried adding a delay (5 secs to be safe) and splitting the whole thing into individual statements, neither helped.

If the animate statements are removed, i.e. only load remains, the problem goes away.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**

sorry for any wasted time, must have been some dodgy ref - after cleaning and restarting the site the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
```

to

```
 div.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
```

explanation:

I'm really not sure what `this` is in the context of `.load()` but you know that `div` is the correct jQuery object

Also, if you haven't aleady, wrap the whole thing inside:

```
$(function(){
   ...
});
```

So that it runs on dom ready

Comment: Bad written fiddle, but nevertheless: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgt8w9z8/1/). It looks like `this` points to `div` in load success callback. So the problem is not in it.

Comment: @andrew: thanks for the suggestion, but it does point to the right div (I can see it in the debugger) and changing to 'div' does not make a difference